# Change background colour of menu link when hovering over menu item

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

EDIT: Just to clarify, I want the link colour to change when I hover over the menu box, not the link. I already have the link colour changing when I hover over it.

I can explain my problem better with screenshots. The cursor isn't showing in them. I only have the Main Menu heading linking to something so far.

This is what the menu looks like normally:
[image]

This is what I want it to look like all the time when hovering over the headings:

[image]

As you can see below, the 'Main Menu' text disappears when I hover over that heading box. It only appears when I hover over the text. In this image I have the cursor at the bottom right of the Main Menu box. In the next image it's hovering over the text. Just pointing out the obvious I suppose.

[image]

[image]

I have all text colour in links set to black as default and white when hovering.
I have the background colour of the menu headings set to black when hovering over them. This is where the problem occurs.

Is there a way to set the colour of the text in links to change to white when the heading box is hovered over and not just when the actual text is hovered over?

```
a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff; 
}
```

Comment: Can we see your CSS that you have for the menu?

Comment: I've added the relevant code. Edit: Solved

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nqkapprm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
ul li:hover a {
     color: #fff;
}
```

This targets the Link inside the menu item, when you hover over the list-item.

Comment: Oh it was that easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give your menu item a class of, say menu_item, and add css.

```
.menu_item:hover {background-color:#000; color:#fff;}
```

Comment: It don't think this will work. From what he is explaining above; Is that the applying the hover effect to the li element and not the a element. Might need a Adjacent selector for this one.